Do google function often give, 502 error on firebase functions:config:get?
Running the firebase command firebase functions:config:get returns an error Error: Unable to parse JSON: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', it was working fine yesterday but today it it not today.
When i run it with --debug i can see the whole call trace and it seems that the google APIs are returning a '502'
[2024-06-19T09:09:54.234Z] <<< [apiv2][status] GET https://runtimeconfig.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/*********/configs 502
Same thing happens if you past that config URL into a browser, you see you get the "cute" error page instead of the expected JSON confg.
Edit:
This went away by lunch time without me having to change anything does this sort of thing happen a lot with Google compute / Firebase functions up until now i have mostly just used auth and firestore, kind of worried that this might be kind of flaky


This is not likely something the volunteers of Stack Overflow can help you solve.  You should reach out to Firebase support to report any problems with the CLI.

Having the same for the last two weeks while doing firebase deploy --only functions
If gives "Error: Cloud Runtime Config is currently experiencing issues, which is preventing your functions from being deployed. Please wait a few minutes and then try to deploy your functions again.
Run firebase deploy --except functions if you want to continue deploying the rest of your project.", and --debug shows 502 for https://runtimeconfig.googleapis.com configs
Appears from nowhere and disappears after several hours
Hope this can be resolved
